# Functions of random variables: relationship between means

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable

Let $x$ be a continuous random variable and $y=f(x)$. The distribution of $x$ is not known. If so,

(a) is there a way to find out the mean of $y$, say $\bar{y}$, as a function of the mean of $x$, represented as $\bar{x}$, for a general $f(x)$? i.e. is there a way to determine $g$, if $\bar{y} = g(\bar{x})$?

(b) What will be $g$ in the particular case $f(x)=\frac{A+B x}{C+D x}$, where $A, B,C \& D$ are real constants?

Comment: $\bar{y}=a\bar{x}+b$ if $y=f(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: Thanks. But I know that in case of a linear relationship it is straight forward. More complicated relationships is my concern, especially the ratio one I had mentioned.

Comment: If f(x) is convex or concave over all values of x in the support of your random variable (r.v.), i.e., all values of x for which your continuous r.v., has positive density, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality to establish an inequality: $EY \ge f(\bar{x})$ if convex and $EY \le f(\bar{x})$ if concave. Equality holds if f is linear, which is both convex and concave. If f is neither convex nor concave over the support of your r.v., then anything is possible, including equality if things work out just right, but that depends on the distribution of the r.v. as well as f.

Comment: Thanks @MarkL.Stone  Assuming that I can prove positive density, is there a simple example for the usage of Jenson's inequality that I can refer to? Any textbook, paper or web links?

Comment: Well, beyond the Wikipedia article, googling resulted in https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_5_jensen's_inequality.php .  The key is proving convexity or concavity of f(x), which although not spelled out in the references, need only hold over the values of x for which the random variable has positive density.  So you're not proving positive density, you're proving either convexity or concavity of f(x) over the values of x for which density is positive; then you apply the inequality in the appropriate direction, depending on whether f(x) is convex or concave.